# calculate fields from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables

table 1:

```
code    datetime        

111    23/07/2013 07:55
222    23/07/2013 07:46
333    23/07/2013 07:47
111    24/07/2013 08:04
```

table 2:

```
code    datetime        

111    23/07/2013 14:59
222    23/07/2013 14:57
333    23/07/2013 14:58
111    24/07/2013 15:03
```

---

result:

```
code    date       workhour

111    23/07/2013    6.2
222    23/07/2013    6.4
333    23/07/2013    6.5
111    24/07/2013    6.1
```

how to get this result from table 1 and table 2?

thanks.

Comment: ask for help. Is different to ask for development.

Comment: just user timediff to your datetime you will get the result

Comment: This is bad design you cant join the table because you dont have an unique field.Create an auto increment column for both tables.

Comment: Coelho ,I thing it's just a simple question for calculate tow fields.
dholakiyaankit , I'll try it thanks.
Mihai , it's a sample for ease understand the real one has unique field thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.code,t1.datetime as date,HOUR(TIMEDIFF(t2.datetime,t1.datetime)) as workhour
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.code=t2.code GROUP BY t1.code
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner join tables by Code field then select (table1.Code, table1.datetime(only date part), difference-between-table2.datetime-and-table1.datetime/converted to hours) from the whole resultset.